# How to get aspnet_Users.UserId for an anonymous user in ASP.NET membership?

Tags: asp.net-membership, anonymous-users

I am trying to get the aspnet membership `UserId` field from an anonymous user.

I have enabled anonymous identification in web.config :

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" />
```

I have also created a profile:

```
<profile>

  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
         connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>

  <properties>
    <add name="Email" type="System.String" allowAnonymous="true"/>
    <add name="SomethingElse" type="System.Int32" allowAnonymous="true"/>
  </properties>

</profile>
```

I see data in my `aspnetdb\aspnet_Users` table for anonymous users that have had profile information set.

```
Userid                                  PropertyNames   PropertyValuesString     
36139818-4245-45dd-99cb-2a721d43f9c5    Email:S:0:17:   me@example.com
```

I just need to find how to get the 'Userid' value.

It is not possible to use :

```
 Membership.Provider.GetUser(Request.AnonymousID, false);
```

The Request.AnonymousID is a different GUID and not equal to 36139818-4245-45dd-99cb-2a721d43f9c5.

Is there any way to get this Userid. I want to associate it with incomplete activity for an anonymous user. Using the primary key of `aspnet_Users` is preferable to having to create my own GUID (which I could do and store in the profile).

This is basically a [dupe of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741893/asp-net-membership-get-userid-of-anonymous-user) but the question was never actually answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the UserId for an anonymous user with this:

string userId = Request.AnonymousID

Answer (score 2):

OK, so  `MemberShip.GetUser()` returns an object of type `MembershipUser`.

Delving more into the tables in the `aspnetdb` database it seems that although a row is created in `aspnet_Users` for all users (even anonymous ones) - a row is NOT created in aspnet_Membership unless the useris actually authenticated/registered.

But, an anonymous user profile (aspnet_Users table ) is given a GUID instead of a `UserName`.

I still haven't found a way to access the `UserId` property of an anonymous user - but I've realized that really the username is the more useful key anyway.

The `UserId` field is present in `aspnet_Users` table also, so if you really need the unique UserId field then you can get it with a 'manual' SQL lookup.